# A contradiction about the Euler's totient function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $\phi(77) = \phi(7) \cdot \phi(11) = (7 - 1)(11 - 1) = 60$

but

> $\phi(25) = \phi(5) \cdot \phi(5) = (5 - 1)(5 - 1) = 16 \neq 20$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\varphi(n)$ is only "weakly multiplicative".  That is, you need $\gcd(n,m)=1$ to get $\varphi(nm)=\varphi(n)\varphi(m)$.

Comment: The formula I like for the totient is if $n = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ then $\phi(n) = \prod [(p_i -1)*p_i^{k_i - 1}$.  From that it very easy to see that $\phi(n*m) = \phi(n)*\phi(m)$ if $m$ and $n$ don't have any prime factors in common and that it isn't true if they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$$ holds only when $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

In your case  $5$ and $5$ are not relatively prime so it does not apply.

You are dealing with $$\phi(p^2)=p(p-1)$$ formula.

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming the totient function is fully multiplicative, it's not, mwahahaha! As you know, the numbers $1$ to $4$ are coprime to $5$. So are the numbers from $6$ to $9$, $11$ to $14$, $16$ to $19$ and $21$ to $24$, so clearly $\phi(5^2)$ is a multiple of $5$. In fact, $\phi(5^n)$ for $n > 1$ is always a multiple of $5$, which is not the case for $\phi(5m)$ when $\gcd(5, m) = 1$.

This can of course be generalized to other powers of odd primes, and multiples of thereof.